# How can I pass a js animation to pure css?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, animation, css-animations

I have a slider with the scrolling animation in javascript, however they ask me to do it in css, I don't have much idea how I can do it.

```
const Ourblog = () => {
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(0);
  const ref = useRef(null);
  const { state } = useFetch('/our-blogs')
  useEffect(() => {
    setWidth(window.innerWidth);
  }, []);

  const handleResize = () => {
    setWidth(window.innerWidth);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
    };
  }, []);

  const nextSlide = () => {
    const slide = ref.current;
    if (width >= 992) {
      slide.scrollLeft += slide.offsetWidth / 2.9;
    } else {
      slide.scrollLeft += slide.offsetWidth / 1.99;
    }
    if (slide.scrollLeft >= slide.scrollWidth - slide.offsetWidth) {
      slide.scrollLeft = 0;
    }
  };
  const previouSide = () => {
    const slide = ref.current;
    if (width >= 992) {
      slide.scrollLeft -= slide.offsetWidth / 2.9;
    } else {
      slide.scrollLeft -= slide.offsetWidth / 1.99;
    }
    if (slide.scrollLeft <= 0) {
      slide.scrollLeft = slide.scrollWidth;
    }
  };
```

I set the reference with useRef and store the width in the state, with this I can show the cards horizontally

Comment: To move an element horizontally, give it a [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) then simply set its relative or absolute position to a new target value, i.e. `ref.current.style.left = "300px"`

Comment: If you try some css transitions and post what you've tried you may get more help.